# DocuSign Date signed pre-filling

Tags: docusignapi

I have an 18 page document with the "Agreement Date" on page 2 and a Single Signature required on page 18.

When I use the following parameters (whether via an HTTPS POST from my server OR via  the DocuSign API Explorer) then the date is getting PRE-FILLED with the date that the envelope was created and appears as such when the signer opens it up to sign it.

I'm using the Sandbox environment. Is there a bug? Might this be something to do with the Time Zone?

```
{
    "documents": [
    {
      "documentBase64": "<Base64BytesHere>",
      "documentId": "1",
      "name": "<document name>"
    }
  ],
  "emailBlurb": "<email blurb>",
  "emailSubject": "<email subject>",
  "recipients": {
    "signers": [
      {
        "email": "<email address of signer>",
        "name": "<name of signer>",
        "recipientId": "1",
        "tabs": {
          "dateSignedTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "font": "TimesNewRoman",
              "fontSize": "Size11",
              "pageNumber": "2",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "xPosition": "235",
              "yPosition": "96"
            }
          ],
          "signHereTabs": [
            {
              "documentId": "1",
              "pageNumber": "18",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "xPosition": "310",
              "yPosition": "351"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the **Date** tab instead of the **Date Signed** tab.

From [Documentation](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipientTabs/)

> - **Date Signed Tab** : Place this tab on the document where you want the date the recipient signed the document to appear.
> - **Date Tab** : Place this tab on the document where you want the recipient to enter a date. Date tabs are single-line fields that allow date information to be entered in any format. The tooltip for this tab recommends entering the date as MM/DD/YYYY, but this is not enforced. The format entered by the signer is retained. If you need a particular date format enforced, DocuSign recommends using a Text tab with a Validation Pattern and Validation Message to enforce the format.

- To prefill the date value, set the **value** property.
- If the Signer should not edit the date value then set the **locked** property to **true**

  ```
          "tabs": {
              "dateTabs": [
                  {
                      "documentId": "1",
                      "pageNumber": "2",
                      "xPosition": "235",
                      "yPosition": "96",
                      "width" : "80",
                      "value": "12/13/2016",
                      "locked" : "true"

                  }
              ]
          }
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I don't want my signer to have to enter today's date. I just want the signer to DocuSign the document, and have the date signed entered automatically.

Comment: If you want to Prefill the date tab then just set the **value** property to whichever date you want.  Updated the answer.

Comment: Alas that wouldn't work either, because it assumes that I already know the date when the signer will sign the document. I don't. That's the whole point of my problem/question !

Comment: "_date is getting PRE-FILLED with the date that the envelope was created_"  .  That is an incorrect statement. If you are using the DateSigned tab then the **date the recipient signed the document** will be placed

Comment: Correct. That is what should happen. But it's not what IS happening. What IS happening is that as soon as the first signer opens the document: voila there is is: The date the document envelope was CREATED.

Comment: Can you give me an envelopeId where this happened?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce the behavior you have suggested. When the **DateSigned** tab is use The date placed in the document is always the date the recipient signed the document.

Comment: Envelope ID: 16e40ff7-c8fc-4b74-acfe-b0de16e592c2 - if you check out that envelope ID it hasn't been signed yet but the date is entered at the top of page 2 as 08 May 2017. If you like I will try tomorrow from the API Explorer because at first it worked OK in there then I started getting the same problem - in fact the JSON in my original question is copy-pasted from the API explorer.

Comment: The envelope was created at **5/8/2017 4:32:03 PM** UTC.   It has not been Signed.  What is the value the signer is seeing on the DateSigned tab?

Comment: It says 08 May 2017 at the top of page 2 where it says "THIS AGREEMENT is made on". If you access the document you can see for yourself: https://demo.docusign.net/Member/EmailStart.aspx?a=7be080e3-ed2d-4585-a039-1ff539a7625b&acct=5997a4cf-5665-4211-abe4-8a70ca110e97&er=fdbad906-3a2f-4e3c-b7eb-88395582c125&espei=16e40ff7-c8fc-4b74-acfe-b0de16e592c2

Comment: What is the issue here? isn't **08 May 2017** the correct value? Since the signer is attempting to sign on **08 May 2017** the document correctly shows the date value. What is the date value you were expecting?

Comment: There are a few extra parms that were sent (and I've omitted the content for brevity): "documents:"[{"documentFields":[]}], "allowReassign": "false", "eventNotification": {}, "enableWetSign":"false"

Comment: The issue is that the date 08 May 2017 is appearing before he has signed, and that if he opens it up tomorrow on 09 May it will STILL say 08 May both before and after he has signed. Believe me - I've tried it! I've even tried creating an envelope and not trying to sign it until the next day. It says the date the envelope was CREATED and it prints it before the document has signed. That is the issue! Try it yourself. Open up that envelope tomorrow.

Comment: Docusign recommend a custom *regex* Validation Pattern string. Just saying "dd/mm/yyyy" isn't enough.

Answer (score 0):

I am such an idiot.

Having set my Time Zone as UTC-London when I set up my account, it had somehow got itself reset back to California time i.e. 8 hours behind.

I'm an early riser and so when I was testing this I was getting unexpected results,

E.g.:

- I create an envelope 8:00pm UK time on 08 May and open it up for
  signing: It said 08 May.
- The following morning at, say 6:00am UK time, I open it up for
  signing: It STILL said 08 May because in California it was 10:00pm on
  08 May.
- Therefore I assumed that the "Date Signed" was being irreversibly 
  stamped as the envelope creation date.

I've just reset my Time Zone back to UTC-London and done some testing and hey presto! every time the envelope is opened up for signing the CORRECT date is being stamped in the "Date Signed" tab.

Anybody else who has this issue: There is no bug: Just double-check your Time Zone settings.

I apologize profusely for wasting everybody's time.